# Place button as LAST column in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I have a grid view and I add columns to it by code:

```
//Retrieve "Table" from database
gridOffers.DataSource = table;
gridOffers.DataBind();
```

The columns added by code are being added AFTER the button, which is not what I need:
[image]
How do I make sure the Add To Cart button the very last thing?

Source of gridView:

```
<Columns>
             <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="ImageUrl" ControlStyle-Width="100"
                ControlStyle-Height = "100" HeaderText = "Preview Image"  
                 ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
<ControlStyle Height="100px" Width="100px"></ControlStyle>

<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
             </asp:ImageField>
             <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" 
                         CommandName="btnAddToCart" Text="Add To Cart" />
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
```

Comment: What worked for you ? I have same issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're defining columns in the GridView source AND by databinding a data source to the GridView. Therefore you have two sources of columns; there may or may not be a guaranteed order in which columns are added to the GridView.

Instead, why not set **AutoGenerateColumns** for the GridView to **False** and then explicitly specify the column order by using **BoundField** for each field you want from the data source in your GridView source followed by your image and button columns?

Comment: I assume that he asks how to control the order of the columns even when `AutoGenerateColumns` **is** set to `true`. The order is guaranteed since the declaratively added controls will be created first  and then then the databound/manually created. That is documented in the [Page's Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)(search "controls created declaratively").

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: whilst I believe you are correct in terms of control creation order, unless I'm missing something the page life cycle link only says that the Init and Load events for a control added at run time might occur later than controls created declaratively. It does include controls in templates of data bound controls as having potentially later events. Since the OP had not explicitly mentioned that keeping AutoGenerateColumns as True was important, I suggested a solution where you can be clear about your intent ie the column order is explicit.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there's a less hacky way, but you could use [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) to change the order, so that the AutoGenerated columns are followed by your other columns:

```
protected void gridOffers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[0];
    e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(0);
    //Move first to the end
    e.Row.Cells.Add(cell);
    cell = e.Row.Cells[0];
    e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(0);
    //Move second to the end
    e.Row.Cells.Add(cell);
}
```

Comment: +1, in my experience there is *not* a less hacky way to do this while still having the auto-generated columns in there.

Comment: +1, Thank you. However I can do without auto generated columns, I just didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `AutoGenerateColumns` set to true on the Gridview? If so set this to false and manually set the fields in the grid using `asp:BoundField` setting the `DataField` to the name of the field from the datasource.

This way you can set the exact order of your columns.

Comment: You can see in the image that he has `AutogenerateColumns=true` ("Auto-generate-fields"). I assume that he asks how to control the order of the columns even when `AutoGenerateColumns` **is** set to `true`.