# Change the order of the commandField in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview which is totatly bounded by programatically .And i added a command field for selection .But it shows up on the first column .Bu i want to change its order to the last column. I tried to use Displayindex  , but that column doesn't involve a headerrow.

Here is my gridview looks like

```
         UserID   UserName  UserAddress 
    -------------------------------------------------
  Select   1      testname  testaddress
```

I just want to pass Select to the last column

```
         UserID   UserName  UserAddress 
    -------------------------------------------------
          1      testname  testaddress   Select 


 <asp:GridView ID="GridForUnits" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"
                        GridLines="None" Style="text-align: left" Width="851px" OnRowDataBound="GridForUnits_RowDataBound"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridForUnits_SelectedIndexChanged1">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                        </Columns>
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Any Help Appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your mark up for the gridview?

Comment: How are you doing the data binding, Is it from a sql data source, are you binding to a data table? can you post all relevant code?

Comment: I am just binding it with dataset.Yes  data comes from back-end

Comment: Why dont you change the VisibleIndex?
Put VisibleIndex to all the columns you have in the order you want them to appear, and the command the last one.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend to not auto generate the columns, fill them manually, and then change the visible index of all of them , setting the select button the last one.

[More explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942668/place-button-as-last-column-in-gridview)

Other solution: move the TableCells around in the RowDataBound event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = e.Row;


        List<TableCell> cells = new List<TableCell>();


        foreach (DataControlField column in GridView1.Columns)
        {
            // Retrieve first cell
            TableCell cell = row.Cells[0];


            // Remove cell
            row.Cells.Remove(cell);


            // Add cell to list
            cells.Add(cell);
        }


        // Add cells
        row.Cells.AddRange(cells.ToArray());
    }
```

[Link to source](http://forums.asp.net/t/1333081.aspx)

Comment: BuT This is part of the project which is totally configurable  and column name and amount may change

Comment: Ok.What if i ptu a accessible header text on the column .Would it be easier to change the order of that particular column ?